# Match data in 2 columns output max third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: info]

Column1 has the unique id, column 2(id, may be repeated) and 3 are linked (info on 3rd column is attached to the id on column2). I want the highest number in column 3 that also matches the unique id.

eg. need to get a result of 15, but my formula:

```
=(INDEX(range3,MATCH($A$4,range2,0)))
```

only gives me the first match. I've been trying to add the Max function but i get errors.

Comment: Does `=MAXIFS(range3,range2,$A$4)` do it for you?

Comment: my excel does not have maxifs function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data range2 & range3 have sorted from small to large, you can use the Lookup function

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/(D$2:D$15=A2),E$2:E$15),"")
```

[image]

Edit :

If range2 & range3 data are not sorted, then `B2` formula using:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,E$2:E$15/(D$2:D$15=A2),1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: i apologize for making it look that way, i chose a small sample of the data. my mistake. range 2 and 3 are not sorted